# Initialize newly allocated memory after expanding a dynamic array of void pointers

Tags: c

I'm learning Zed Shaw's Learn C the Hard Way. I'm confused by the code of the definition of a function in ex34. In ex34, Zed teaches us how to implement a dynamic array. Code in darray.h:

```
typedef struct DArray {
  int end;
  int max;
  size_t element_size;
  size_t expand_rate; /* it's 300 by default. */
  void **contents;
} DArray;

DArray *DArray_create(size_t element_size, size_t initial_max);
int DArray_expand(DArray *array);
/* other operations... */
```

The code confused me is in darray.c:

```
DArray *DArray_create(size_t element_size, size_t initial_max)
{
  DArray *array = malloc(sizeof(DArray));
  array->max = initial_max;
  array->contents = calloc(initial_max, sizeof(void *));
  array->end = 0;
  array->element_size = element_size;
  array->expand_rate = DEFAULT_EXPAND_RATE; /* defined in header, which is 300 */

  return array;
}

static inline int DArray_resize(DArray *array, size_t newsize)
{
  array->max = newsize;
  void *contents = realloc(array->contents, array->max * sizeof(void *));
  array->contents = contents;
  return 0;
}

int DArray_expand(DArray *array)
{
  size_t old_max = array->max;
  DArray_resize(array, array->max + array->expand_rate);
  memset(array->contents + old_max, 0, array->expand_rate + 1); // confused

  return 0;
}
/* Definitions of other operations... */
```

[The link of the exercise...](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex34.html)

So my question is, why the third argument of the `memset` called by `DArray_expand` is `array->expand_rate + 1` instead of `array->expand_rate`? I think the length of the array after expanding is 400 (given that the initial length is 100) ranging from `contents[0]` to `contents[399]`. The elements need to be initialized are ranging from `contents[100]` to `contents[399]`, then the third argument of `memset` should be `array->expand_rate` which is 300. Could anyone explain it to me?

Thanks for editing my post. I forgot that I can use inline code md syntax.

---

EDIT: I'm confused by the use of memset in this code too. The man page of memset in my computer said:

> The memset() function writes len bytes of value c (converted to an unsigned char) to the byte string b.

I've googled the implementation of memset. And I got this from this link:

[C standard library:string.h:memset](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_standard_library%3astring.h%3amemset)

```
#include <stddef.h> /* size_t */
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n)
{
    unsigned char* p=s;
    while(n--)
        *p++ = (unsigned char)c; // This line confused me..
    return s;
}
```

In my OS(Darwin 12.0.0), the value of `sizeof(void *)` and `sizeof(int *)` is 8. I've tried some more. It seems size of all kinds of pointer in my OS is 8. If the size of pointer is 8, then what happens in this code:

```
*p++ = (unsigned char)c; /* the value of c is 0. size of 
                            unsigned char is 1 in my OS */
```

If Zed's code have bugs, could you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: *Learn C the hard way*, i,e, from a flawed book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+1` is likely bonkers or a code smell at the very least. Also, the `memset` function writes `n` bytes:

> The  memset()  function fills the **first n bytes** of the memory area
>   pointed to by s withthe constant byte c

As such, it should likely be `array->expand_rate * sizeof(void *)`.

---

Moreover, `memset` to 0 isn't a bulletproof way to make pointers NULL. On some exotic architectures **[all-bits-0 doesn't necessarily mean `NULL`](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html)**.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't carefully read the code or the explanation page. But it does look flawed and overly contrived at any rate.

Comment: I agree. He forgot to mention "fix my bugs" in his section **How to Improve It**.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by bonkers? And I'm confused by memset too.

Comment: @Joe.Jeong Just some slang meaning "bad / wrong" in this context. Read the `memset` manual page, it's not meant for writing NULL pointers.

Comment: Nothing in the code actually depends on unused elements being initialized to NULL. So that line can just be removed.

Comment: Thanks, @cnicutar I think I know how to fix it. Just set every element of the array to NULL through a loop. Am I right? This is the first time I ask a question since I get a account on SO. And thanks all the people help me in this post.

Comment: @Joe.Jeong A loop is just what you need :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the statement is wrong

```
memset(array->contents + old_max, 0, array->expand_rate + 1);
```

This might lead to access out of bounds of the array

It should be

```
memset(array->contents + old_max, 0, array->expand_rate * sizeof(void *));
```

**EDIT:**
Also, as mentioned correctly by cnicutar, above, it should be `array->expand_rate * sizeof(void *)`. I had missed this point and modified it after seeing cnicutar's answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Jay. I think I know how to fix it.